# convert a lambda expression from C# to vb.net

Tags: linq, c#-to-vb.net

hello evry one and thank you for your help, I really need to convert this C# lambda expression into VB.NET ?

```
 var res = (from v in initialList
                           group v by v.entityId into grp
                           select grp.OrderByDescending(v => v.gpsDate).First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. LINQPad is your friend.

```
Dim res = (From v In initialList
           Group v By v.entityId Into grp = Group
           Select grp.OrderByDescending(Function(v) v.gpsDate).First()).ToList
```